# How to generate new djvu file from a djvu file?

Tags: djvu

I have a djvu file that has 20 pages say.

How do I generate a new djvu file that has a selected number only out of those 20 pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow this manual http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Help:DjVu_files#Splitting_DjVu_files to produce resulting DJVU only with the pages you have specified.